# How to check if the value is NULL then pick the one that is not null per PolicyNumber. SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For PolicyNumber ENV1 if PolicyType is NULL then I need to pick up the one that is not null, which is 'Primary'.

Same with policy ENV3: ID 005 has null value, so it needs to pick up next that is not null, for `PolicyNumber` ENV3, which should be `'Claim Made'`

Is any way to achieve that without grouping it?

```
declare @TestTable table 
                   (
                       ID int,  
                       PolicyNumber varchar(50), 
                       PolicyType varchar(50)
                   )

insert into @TestTable 
values (001, 'ENV1','Primary'), (002, 'ENV1',NULL),
       (003, 'ENV2','Claim Made'), (004, 'ENV3','Claim Made'),
       (005, 'ENV3',NULL)

select 
    ID,  
    PolicyNumber, 
    PolicyType
from
    @TestTable
```

Output:

```
ID  PolicyNumber    PolicyType
-------------------------------
1   ENV1            Primary
2   ENV1            NULL
3   ENV2            Claim Made
4   ENV3            Claim Made
5   ENV3            NULL
```

Comment: You can use `LAG` if you are on 2012+. Can you tag the version of SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, its SQL Server  2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
declare @TestTable table (ID int,  PolicyNumber varchar(50), PolicyType varchar(50))
insert into @TestTable values 
                       (001, 'ENV1','Primary'),
                       (002, 'ENV1',NULL),
                       (003, 'ENV2','Claim Made'),
                       (004, 'ENV3','Claim Made'),
                       (005, 'ENV3',NULL)

select  ID,  
        PolicyNumber, 
        PolicyType = case when PolicyType is null then lag(PolicyType) over (partition by PolicyNumber order by ID) else PolicyType end
from @TestTable
```

Naturally, if there are consecutive `NULL` values, we can handle this a couple of ways. Here is one:

```
declare @TestTable table (ID int,  PolicyNumber varchar(50), PolicyType varchar(50))
insert into @TestTable values 
                       (001, 'ENV1','Primary'),
                       (002, 'ENV1',NULL),
                       (003, 'ENV2','Claim Made'),
                       (004, 'ENV3','Claim Made'),
                       (005, 'ENV3',NULL),
                       (006, 'ENV3',NULL)

select  t.ID,  
        t.PolicyNumber, 
        PolicyType = case when t.PolicyType is null then (select top 1 PolicyType 
                                                          from @TestTable 
                                                          where PolicyType is not null 
                                                               and PolicyNumber = t.PolicyNumber
                                                          order by ID desc) 
                         else PolicyType end
from @TestTable t
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks for such a great answer!

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using window functions:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(policy_number,
                max(policynumber) over (partition by id)
               ) as new_policy_number
from t;
```

Comment: I believe it's `max(PolicyType) over (partition by PolicyNumber)`